# Como faço para retornar a quantidade de linhas que aparecem com um determinado começo?

Tags: array, perl

Eu queria abrir um documento e fazer com que ele retornasse para mim o último número de uma linha que contem `'>'` como referência. Isso de todas as linhas que tenham esse `'>'`.
ou que ele lesse a quantidade de `'>'` que existissem no arquivo e me retornasse na forma de que eu pudesse colocar cada número desse (1, 2, 3..) em uma variável.

O dado aparece dessa forma:

> '>'VE05.fasta.screen.Contig1
>   TTTTGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTATTTAATTTTTTTCTTTGGGGGGGG
>   GGAAAATTTTTTTTTCCCTCCCTTCTACAACACAAGAAAAAAAAACTTCC
>   '>'VE05.fasta.screen.Contig2
>   TTTTGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTATTTAATTTTTTTCTTTGGGGGGGG
>   GGAAAATTTTTTTTTCCCTCCCTTCTACAACACAA

Eu fiz esse código, mas sei que está incompleto.

```
open (my @number, '<', @n);

@number = chop (); 

print "Contig's final number:@num";

close @n;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**open ([FILEHANDLE, '[TIPO ABERTURA DO ARQUIVO]',[DIRETORIO/ARQUIVO] );**

Se o array @n contém as informações do arquivo leia diretamente o array:

```
open my $new_file, '>', 'new_sequence_file'
        or die "Not possible open file"; 

for my $row (@n){

  if ( $row =~ /^'>'/){
    print $new_file ++$sequence.$row, "\n";

  }else{
    print $new_file $row, "\n";
  }
}
```

Caso necessite ler diretamente o arquivo:

## Abrindo em modo de leitura

```
open my $fh, '<', '/usr/bin/TESTE/new_sequence_file.txt'
        or die "Not possible open file"
```

## Criando um novo arquivo para tratar o sequencial, mas caso queira pode sobrescrever o arquivo principal.

```
open my $new_file, '>>', 'new_sequence_file'
        or die "Not possible open file"; 

for ( my $row = $fh) ){

  if ( $row =~ /^'>'/){
    print $new_file ++$sequence.$row, "\n";

  }else{
    print $new_file $row, "\n";
  }
}
```

## Saída:

```
1'>'VE05.fasta.screen.Contig1
TTTTGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTATTTAATTTTTTTCTTTGGGGGGGG
GGAAAATTTTTTTTTCCCTCCCTTCTACAACACAAGAAAAAAAAACTTCC
2'>'VE05.fasta.screen.Contig2
TTTTGTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTATTTAATTTTTTTCTTTGGGGGGGG
GGAAAATTTTTTTTTCCCTCCCTTCTACAACACAA
```

Se precisar contar a header de lote que contém '>' utilize a variavel $sequence